# Docker.sock accessable from azure web app multi container

Tags: azure, traefik, azure-container-instances

Can you access docker API from Traefik inside an azure multi-container app? I am getting path mapping errors when I attempt this.

Comment: What Docker API do you mean? In the Web App Service Plan or others?

Comment: I should combine this and my other question... They are kind of merging in the problem. I want to use Traefik to route to all my microservices in a multicontainer web app on azure. That is the end game but in my other question I'm having issues accessing the ports via a static Traefik config and here it would be nice to access the other container info via the docker.sock path in the web app service.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an infrastructure with Trafik and other microservices work in the Azure Web App like in docker compose? And now they cannot connect through the Trafik with the port?

Comment: Correct. Connection refused on port 3000 etc

Comment: With the document [multi-container app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app), there just show that the services connect each other with the setting in the compose file and the app setting. So you can try to use [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#app-settings). I think it woould be helpful.